# Why is this html not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have this short piece of code:

```
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#term").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
          dataType: 'JSONP',
          data: {
            format: 'json',
            q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + '"'
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, function(item) {
              return { label: item.suggestion.data, value: item.suggestion.data };
            }));
          }
        });
      }
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

  <label for="term">Search term: </label>
  <input id="term" />

</body>
</html>
```

It is working good online at JsBin: [JsBin preview](http://jsbin.com/epikim/4/edit#javascript,html,live)

However when I copy code to desktop so I can work with it it doesn't work (it used to work however) What am I doing wrong?? Why is this not working except online??

Comment: the only reason i can think of is to wrap the js code inside the `ready` handler, like `$(document).ready(function(){//your code here});`

Comment: Have you looked for errors in your console ?

Comment: Placing the code 'beneath' the input/label instead of head also seems to work..(feel stupid now)

Comment: @Youss you are welcome, i have made it an answer `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try wrapping the javascript code inside the ready handler, jsbin does it automatically

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your code here
});
```

or the short cut

```
$(function(){

//your code here
});
```

this wil execute the script once the DOM has finished loading, or as an alternative you can place the javascript at the end of the document so it is executed when the DOM has loaded

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the input element before it has been created. Perform your autocompletion initialization after the DOM elements have been set up.

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#term").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
                    dataType: 'JSONP',
                    data: {
                        format: 'json',
                        q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + '"'
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.suggestion.data,
                                value: item.suggestion.data
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
...
```